# Why do I receive "use of undeclared identifier 'viewDidLoad'" error?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I keep Getting "use of undeclared identifier 'viewDidLoad'" error in Xcode can anyone help me with this

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self)
        // Custom initialization


    return self;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadInitialData];
}
```

Comment: Rob's comment is most likely correct but it would really help if you clarified exactly where the issue is happening in your code and to post the complete error message.

Comment: Is this your actual code cut-and-paste as-is? If so, you're missing a return statement.

Comment: your class looks like subclass of `UITableView` not `UIViewController` , so its super class won't have `viewDidLoad`. what are you try to do? you can initialize in `initWithStyle:`

Comment: @user3663250 While my original conjecture was that you may have subclassed the wrong class (one that didn't implement `viewDidLoad`), I now realize that this particular "undeclared identifier" error is more likely a result of mismatched braces in the code immediately preceding the `viewDidLoad` method. It's a little confusing, but an extraneous mismatched open brace in the previous method can generate an errors just like this.